# Open a File Share link from Window.open javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to open a  file share link  from the window.open ....... but its adding the http://localhost/vdir/    before the path   can any one say what is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by file share link?

Comment: please show a full example. We're not psychics.

Comment: Ok i solved it by adding file://  to share drive path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it by adding file:// to share drive path

Comment: While we're glad you found a solution, can you please elaborate on the original problem so that others might find your question and solution useful?

Comment: I am sorry if i was not clear.  I was trying to open the  fileshare link ex. var str= \\servername\fildername\x.pdf  from window.open(str) in a javasscript since i am not using file protocal  file:     the new window is opening with 
 http://localhost/vdir/ \\servername\fildername\x.pdf  which is going no where .  Adding  file: before str had solved my issue

Thanks